# get specific data in an object array and delete its rows (stripe google apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to delete the rows that has a 0 value on it

here's my code

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3");

var getLengthCol = getLengthColumn(sheet,'A:A');
var countColLength = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < getLengthCol.length; i++)
  {
    if(getLengthCol[i] != '')
    {
      countColLength = i+1;
    }
  }

  // var rowData = getDataFromOrig.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,countColLength,1).getValues();
var rowData = sheet.getRange(2,1,countColLength,1).getValues();

  for(var i = 0 ; i < rowData.length; i++)
  {
    if(rowData[i] == 0)
    {
      sheet.deleteRows(rowData[i]);
    }
  }
```

here's the data

[image]

I am trying to delete all the rows that has 0 value on the first column.

but i am getting this error

> Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `unit_amount` from the response value.
- In your script, the value of `Logger.log(res.getContentText());` is the value of your sample image.
- You have already got the value from the API.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices";
var params = {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX:")
  }
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
Logger.log(res.getContentText());
var responseValue = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
var values = responseValue.data.map(({ unit_amount }) => unit_amount);
console.log(values) // You can see the values of "unit_amount" at the log.
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I couldn't understand about the output format you expect. So when the result value of my modified script is not the result you expect, can you provide the sample output values? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

From your following replying,

> Thank you for the answer but I found a work around for my problem because I am getting already the value I don't need to use GET operation . but what I am trying to do actually is that if the amount = 0 then i will delete its data on the row. that's all thank you though

You want to retrieve the values when the values of `unit_amount` is not `0`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification using `filter`?

#### From:

```
var values = responseValue.data.map(({ unit_amount }) => unit_amount);
```

#### To:

```
var values = responseValue.data.filter(({ unit_amount }) => unit_amount != 0).map(({ unit_amount }) => [unit_amount]);
```

or, when `reduce` is used, it becomes as follows.

```
var values = responseValue.data.reduce((ar, { unit_amount }) => {
  if (unit_amount != 0) ar.push([unit_amount]);
  return ar;
}, []);
```

- If you want to retrieve 1 dimensional array, about above script, please modify from `[unit_amount]` to `unit_amount`.

### Added 2:

I noticed that your question had been changed. For your updated question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `getLengthColumn` in your script. But, in order to achieve your new goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
sheet
  .getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()) // Retrieve the range. In this case, column A is retrieved.
  .createTextFinder("0") // Search 0 in the column A using TextFinder.
  .matchEntireCell(true) // The cell is retrieved when the cell value is the same with 0.
  .findAll() // Here, the searched result is returned. In this case, the ranges are returned as an array.
  .reverse() // Reverse the array.
  .forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow())); // Delete rows using loop.
```

- In this sample script, the rows which have `0` in the cell value are retrieved using TextFinder and delete them.

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I found a work around for my problem because I am getting already the value I don't need to use GET operation . but what I am trying to do actually is that if the amount = 0 then i will delete its data on the row. that's all thank you though

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `but what I am trying to do actually is that if the amount = 0 then i will delete its data on the row.`, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. If above modified script is not useful, can you provide the sample output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: I don't think filter works on google app script sir . I am not using any trigger or anything I just run automatically.

Comment: please don't apologize sir.

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I don't think filter works on google app script sir . I am not using any trigger or anything I just run automatically.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, I cannot still understand about your output you expect. Also I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample output you expect? By the way, you have already been able to retrieve the value from the API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes that is correct sir . What I am trying to do sir is that after getting the data from the post method i stored it from an array so like this `message[2] = params.payload.unit_amount;` and it is inside a for loop statement , now from that for loop what i am trying to do is that if this `data.[unit_amount] = 0` then i will delete it from the spreadsheet row . that is what i am trying to do sir right now.

Comment: it always says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. About `What I am trying to do sir is that after getting the data from the post method i stored it from an array so like this message[2] = params.payload.unit_amount;`, in your script, GET method is used. So your actual situation is different from your script in your question? I'm confusing from this. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: @Tanaike And, in order to correctly understand about your situation, it is required to confirm your situation. At first, the value of `Logger.log(res.getContentText())` is the value of your sample image. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, what are `message[2] = params.payload.unit_amount;` and `data.[unit_amount] = 0`? And, can you provide your current script for replicating the issue of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: I got it now sir . Thank you . from your question I came up with an idea . Thank you very much

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, I'm glad. But if your issue was not resolved, feel free to tell me. I would like to support you.

Comment: actually can i just change may question above sir regarding on deleting rows?

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I noticed that your question had been changed. For your new goal, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: This is perfect . but could you explain line by line sir if you don't mind so that i can understand more of that.

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I apologize for the inconvenience. About the proposed script, I added the explanation in the script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: why do I need to reverse the array sir? just curious

Comment: sir can you help me out with this please . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195211/create-an-invoice-stripe-using-google-app-script

Comment: @Ginxxx Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When `reverse` is not used, the rows are deleted from top of sheet. In this case, the next row number for deleting is changed every delete. By this, the script becomes a bit complicated. So in order to delete rows from the bottom of sheet, I used `reverse`. In this case, the row number is not changed every delete. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @Ginxxx About `sir can you help me out with this please . stackoverflow.com/questions/67195211/…`, when I saw it now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. It will resolve your issue.